# How to verify security of meekrodb?

Tags: security, sql-injection

[Meekrodb](http://www.meekro.com/) is a simple php-->mysql library. How do I test/verify that it is secure, such as against sql injection attacks?

Comment: It claims that it is 100% SQL injection proof. Not good enough for you?

Comment: if you're going to downvote, then you should explain why ... otherwise your downvote is just harassment.

Answer (score 4):

The *first option* is to read the FAQ:

**Are there any extra precautions I should take to prevent SQL injection?**

MeekroDB makes SQL injection 100% impossible if you follow 2 simple rules. First, never use the %l (literal) placeholder with user-supplied data. This placeholder doesn't escape your data the way all of the others do. Second, never change the character set at runtime using MySQL commands SET NAMES or SET CHARACTER SET. If you need to change the character set, only use DB::$encoding at the same place where you set your MySQL username/password.

The *second option*, assuming you have a license:

Use a query/input field by filling in:

```
'\"
```

Which could potentially cause the weirdest errors you have ever seen. It might just be converted, in which case you prove it's secure.

**Update**

For example, going from there first claim (in combination with security):

*"MeekroDB takes care of quotes and escaping for you."*

Now for testing this specific claim they have provided there way of handling this situation:

```
DB::query("SELECT * FROM login WHERE username=%s AND password=%s", 
                                                        $username, 
                                                        $password);
```

To prove that this claim is actually true, you could write a small application which would (for example) input:

```
$username = "''""\";
```

Comment: thanks Floris for your time. However I am wondering how to verify their claims ...

Comment: Assuming you mean the claims on the front page. I think it would be best to make a prototype application which displays abuse of input (even if this is hardcoded) being handled properly.

Comment: true ... but I have no idea where to begin to try to 'attack' it.

Comment: @dsdsdsdsd I have updated my answer to provide a clear way of testing it. Should you be seeking information on SQL injection itself I would like to refer to this article: http://www.unixwiz.net/techtips/sql-injection.html

Comment: I suppose, though, that there are many many ways of abusing a php/mysql channel, other than just the common sql injection schemes ... so I suppose I am wondering about the larger picture of potential threat techniques, rather than just that one particular technique.